# Text equality (including null values) in Postgres plpgsql stored function

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, equals, plpgsql

I have a stored function which is supposed to compare three text values for equality. Some of these text values may be null, and if they are, then the comparison should return a false value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "subject_check_if_subjectName_exists"(name1IN text, name2IN text, name3IN text, name4IN text)
returns boolean as
$$
declare
    results boolean;
    subjectList record;
begin
    results = false;
    for subjectList in select name1, name2, name3, name4 from subject loop
    if (name1In = subjectList.name1) and (name2In = subjectList.name2) and (name3In = subjectList.name3) and (name4In = subjectList.name4)
      then
        results = true;
        EXIT; -- exit out of loop
    end if;
    end loop;
    return results;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Of both name4IN and subjectList.name4 are null, and all the other values are equal, the function doesn't return a true value - which it should. How can I compare these text values even if they are null (null = null should return true)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to use [`is not distinct from`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html):

> For non-null inputs, `IS DISTINCT FROM` is the same as the `<>` operator. However, if both inputs are null it returns false, and if only one input is null it returns true. Similarly, `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` is identical to `=` for non-null inputs, but it returns true when both inputs are null, and false when only one input is null.

Essentially, `A is not distinct from B` is like `A = B` but it treats NULLs as "equal" (i.e. it behaves like most SQL newcomers think `=` should). For example, consider a simple function like this:

```
create function f(text,text) returns text as $$
begin
    if $1 is distinct from $2 then
        return '!=';
    end if;
    return '==';
end $$
language plpgsql;
```

That will give you results like this:

```
=> select f(null, null) as "1"
          f(null, '') as "2",
          f('', '') as "3",
          f('pancakes','pancakes') as "4",
          f('pancakes', null) as "5",
          f('pancakes', 'house') as "6";
 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  
----+----+----+----+----+----
 == | != | == | == | != | !=
```

So something like this is what you're looking for:

```
if (name1In is not distinct from subjectList.name1) and ...
```

Comment: Exactly. Thank you for putting my question correctly. Not so good with explaining myself. I will try this asap. I've written out the function that works with multiple if statements ... but IS NOT DISTINCT FROM seems a much faster way to go about it. Please see next answer.

Comment: @user1295681: And much easier than trying to make sure you cover all the cases with a pile of nest `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

Use coalesce:

```
if (coalesce(name1In, '') = coalesce(subjectList.name1, '') ....
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I've read that coalesce returns the first not null value in a list ... and I'm getting this error when running the same stored procedure with this modified if statement: `if (coalesce(name1IN, '') = coalesce(subjectList.name1), '') then
  results = true;
  exit;
 end if;` This is the error: `********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "(f,"")"
SQL state: 22P02
Context: PL/pgSQL function "subject_check_if_subjectName_exists" line 7 at IF`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, this is what I want to do. I figured there must be a quicker way to compare values including null ones. This does what I want it to do:

```
-- Function to check subject names (name1,2,3 and 4) already exists
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "subject_check_if_subjectName_exists"(name1IN text, name2IN text, name3IN text, name4IN text)
returns boolean as
$$
declare
    results boolean;
    subjectList record;
begin
    results = false;
    for subjectList in select name1, name2, name3, name4 from subject loop
    if ((subjectList.name4 is null) and (name4IN is null)) then
        if ((subjectList.name3 is null) and (name3IN is null)) then
        if ((subjectList.name2 is null) and (name2IN is null)) then
          if (name1IN = subjectList.name1) then
            results = true;
            EXIT;
          end if;
        else
          if ((name1IN = subjectList.name1) and (name2IN = subjectList.name2)) then
            results = true;
            EXIT;
          end if;
        end if;
        else
          if ((name1IN = subjectList.name1) and (name2IN = subjectList.name2) and (name3IN = subjectList.name3)) then
        results = true;
        EXIT;
          end if;
        end if;
    else
      if ((name1IN = subjectList.name1) and (name2IN = subjectList.name2) and (name3IN = subjectList.name3) and (name4IN = subjectList.name4)) then
        results = true;
        EXIT;
          end if;
    end if;
    end loop;
    return results;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Will try IS NOT DISTINCT FROM now.

Thank you for your help. Much appreciated!